# Renaming an AD user (CN) VBS

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I have tried 2 ways (changing CN parameter and movehere) to rename a user in AD, without success. Everything else works (changing name, surname, alias...)

Help appreciated,
Marius

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN on `IADsContainer::MoveHere`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The **IADsContainer::MoveHere** method can
>   be used either to rename an object
>   within the same container or to move
>   an object among different containers.
>   Moving an object retains the object
>   RDN, whereas renaming an object alters
>   the RDN.
>
> For example, the following code
>   example performs the rename action.
>
> ```
> set cont = GetObject("LDAP://dc=dom,dc=com") 
> set newobj = cont.MoveHere("LDAP://cn=Jeff Smith,dc=dom,dc=com", "cn=Denise Smith")
> ```